# Is the optimum of this problem convex in the constraint parameter?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-optimization, convexity, nonlinear-optimization, multivariable-calculus

Let  $f:\mathbb R^+ \to \mathbb R$ be a smooth function, satisfying $f(1)=0$, and suppose that 
$|f|$ grows with the distance from $1$: $|f(x)|$ is strictly increasing when $x \ge 1$, and strictly decreasing when $x \le 1$.

Suppose also that $\lim_{x \to \infty} |f(x)| = \infty$.
For any $s \in (0,1)$, define
$$
F(s)=\min_{xy=s,x,y>0} f^2(x)+ f^2(y) 
$$

(The minimum exists since $|f|$ diverges at infinity.)

> **Question:** Does there exist a convex function $g(s)$ such that $F=g^p$ for some $p \ge 1$? I do not require $g$ to be positive.

Here are two examples where this happens:

**Linear penalization:** $f(x)=x-1$. In that case
$$F(s) =
\begin{cases}
2(\sqrt{s}-1)^2,  & \text{ if  }\, s \ge \frac{1}{4} \\
1-2s, & \text{ if  }\, s \le \frac{1}{4}
\end{cases}
$$
is convex, since $F'(s)$ is non-decreasing.

**Logarithmic penalization:** $f(x)=\log x$. In that case
$$ F(s)=2f^2(\sqrt s)=\frac{1}{2}(\log s)^2$$ is **not** convex.

However, we have $F(s)=g^2(s)$ where $g(s)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\log s$ which is convex.

Is there a general phenomena lying behind these two examples?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. This was a typo (fixed now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. E.g., let $f(x):=|x-1|^{3/2}$. Then 
$$
F(s)=\begin{cases}
 F_1(s) &\text{ if } 0<s\le1/9, \\
 F_2(s) &\text{ if } 1/9\le s<1,
\end{cases}
$$
where 
$$F_1(s):=1 - 3 s - 2s^{3/2},$$
$$F_2(s):=2 + 6 s - 2(3 + s)s^{1/2}.$$
One may note here that $F_1(1/9)=16/27=F_2(1/9)$ and $F'_1(1/9)=-4=F'_2(1/9)$.

From the definition of $F$, it is clear that $F>0$ on $(0,1)$. So, letting $a:=1/p\in(0,1]$, we see that the desired goal was that 
$h:=F^a$
be either convex or (if $p$ is even) concave. 
(If $h$ is concave and $p$ is even, we can take $g:=-h$. Then $g$ will be convex and we will also have $g^p=h^p=F$.)
So, letting $h_j:=F_j^a$ for $j=1,2$, we see that we must have one of the following cases:

(i) $h_1$ is convex on $(0,1/9]$ and $h_2$ is convex on $[1/9,1)$;

(ii) $h_1$ is concave on $(0,1/9]$ and $h_2$ is concave on $[1/9,1)$.

However, $h_1''(1/9)$ equals $3a-4$ in sign and hence is $<0$ for $a\in(0,1]$, whereas $h_2''(1/9)$ equals $2+3a$ in sign and hence is $>0$ for $a\in(0,1]$. So, neither one of the cases (i) or (ii) can take place.

Here is the graph of $F''$:

[image]

Comment: On a second thought, I think that the answer could be remedied as follows: Looking at $\text{sgn}(h_1^{''})=\text{sgn}\big((a-1)F_1^{'}+F_1F_1^{''}\big)$ when $s \to 0$ we must have $h_1^{''}(s)<0$ for sufficiently small $s$. Indeed, since $F_1$ and $F_1^{'}$ tend to finite values at zero, but $F_1''$ tend to $-\infty$, the  sum $(a-1)F_1^{'}+F_1F_1^{''}$ must be negative (here we also use the fact that $F_1$ is positive-and in fact tends to $1$ at zero). Do you agree with my analysis?

Comment: @AsafShachar : My calculation was correct. The mistake is actually in your calculation of the expression for $h''$, which must have $F'^2$ in place of $F'$.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, this was a silly mistake of mine. This is a great answer. I have one more question if you will: Can you say why did you delete your previous example with $f(x)=(x-1)^2$ instead of $f(x)=|x-1|^{\frac{3}{2}}$? In particular, I wonder whether the fact that $f(x)=|x-1|^{\frac{3}{2}}$ is non-smooth was essential in this non-convexity phenomenon, or is it possible to produce counter-examples with smooth $f$. Also, I wonder if you used some program for calculating the minimum $F(s)$ or just calculus...Thanks.

Comment: @AsafShachar : I replaced $f(x):=|x-1|^2$ by $f(x):=|x-1|^{3/2}$ to simplify the resulting expressions. Concerning the smoothness condition on $f$: I'd understand that it can be added hoping that it can help avoid technical complications in a proof of a positive answer. However, I don't see a good point in insisting that this condition be satisfied in a counterexample.

Comment: Previous comment continued: Yet, if you want to insist on the smoothness of $f$, there is a choice: either (i) go back to $f(x):=|x-1|^2$ (found in previous edits) and then deal with the more complicated expressions or (ii) approximate $f(x):=|x-1|^{3/2}$ near $x=0$ (say uniformly) by a smooth function so that the resulting **strict** inequalities hold.

Comment: Thank you. I agree with you that the insistence on smoothness in a counterexample is not very natural here. I wonder whether there are natural conditions which imply that $F(s)$ would be convex.

Comment: By the way, did you use Mathematica or some other program for deriving these expressions for the minimum? (I managed to do it analytically by hand, but this was non-trivial).

Comment: At this point, I don't know of natural conditions which imply that $F$ is convex. Yes, I did use Mathematica -- glad to hear you managed to check this by hand.